# Android gps coordinates location updates

Tags: android, gps

I want to develop an app that receive from the server coordinates every 10 seconds and update the location on the map. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

On how to obtain the GPS coordinates look here:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

You can set the update interval to 10 seconds in the LocationRequest object.

For integrating a map in your app and setting markers on it you can look here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start (for google maps)
or use some alternative provider for maps data like OpenStreetMap (see https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid).

Edit: Maybe you should start with a tutorial like this one: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-google-maps-for-android-basics--cms-24635

Comment: do you have any idea how can i update the coordinates in the onMapReady method? i see that in this method the coordinats are default.

Comment: Getting the coordinates and updating the map are two different things. You could e.g. set the marker (call the addMarker method) as soon as you have your first location update from the FusedLocationAPI. You don't have to set the marker inside the onMapReady() method.

Comment: I added a link for a tutorial in my answer.